# Manage visibility of Tabs, Rows, Columns, Cells ….. based on accessibility (and/or variable)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My sample document.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g1fPSiuYRDElCjuUhHPJu54rS-EjCM-vlV0SedHj1RE/edit?usp=sharing

For the current example assume that there are currently 2 users (# 1 is owner, while # 2 is editor).
Except editor and owner, we are willing to share (i.e. anyone with the link can view) the document with other viewers.

I would like to be able to limit visibility to viewers (anyone with the link can view). Here is how i see it:

**a) Set (in a tab) visibility of single TABS (+ ability to set visibility of Cells/Rows/Columns of visible tabs)**

Owner + Editor can set visibility/accessiblity of single tabs.  This will be done  in a tab (in my example is the “SET_VISIBLE” tab).
(BY DEFAULT) This tab will be only visible to Owner + Editor

Column A (of “SET_VISIBLE” tab) Owner or Editor will add tabs names.
Column B (of “SET_VISIBLE” tab) Owner or Editor will be able to set tabs as Visible (y) or Non Visible (n)

Columns C, D or E (of “SET_VISIBLE” tab) Owner or Editor **could** highlight which cells, rows, columns to be hidden to viewers.

**b) Hide some rows/cells (in a visible tab)**

Owner or Editor could, if what written above for column c, d, e is not possible/too difficult, simply set Columns, Rows or Cells visibility directly in a visible tab (maybe in a column @ the end of the content).  Column (hidden to viewers) will set visibility and hide content (to viewers).

Questions:

1. what is the best way to handle what written above?
2. Could you please post a sample script and/or link me some DIY resources?
3. in case of a script written by the editor (not owner of sheet), owner needs to authorize it?

Comment: Are you familiar with JS? If so, take a look at the Google Apps Script [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) & [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials). Start by just figuring out how to get the value in a cell. Then figure out to how to use that value to access a tab. Eventually, you'll have put it all together. Editors will have full access to write the script. Each user must authorize the script for themselves, if [authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization) is required.

Comment: Diego,
thanks a lot for your help.

would you mind giving me "just" little more details on what you've written: 
"Start by just figuring out how to get the value in a cell. Then figure out to how to use that value to access a tab"...

You mean a script that will read a value in a cell (let's say a character) and if character is "a" (or whatever) access a given tab?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets – The first code example in the "Reading data" section.